# Compound interest on python comes out incorrect

Tags: python, math

Compound interest on 1,500,000 of 5% for 1 year (I'm using 1 year as a test) should be 75,000. But in python, using this formula with principle = 1500000, rate = 5, time = 1:

```
Amount = principle * pow(1+rate/100, time)
```

I get:  76,515.08

Why is the number 1,515.08 higher than it should be?

Here is the entire program:

```
def compound_interest(principle, rate, time):

principle=int(principle)
rate=int(rate)
time=int(time)
Amount = principle * pow(1+rate/100, time)
CI = Amount - principle
return CI

print("Amount to start?")
a = float(input())
print("Years?")
y = float(input())
print("Rate as percentage?")
r = float(input())

c = compound_interest(a,y,r)
t = a + c
print("Starting value: " + "${:,.2f}".format(a))
print("Compound interest: " + "${:,.2f}".format(c))
print("New principle: " + "${:,.2f}".format(t))
```

Comment: I get an interest of 75,000 e.g. `1500000 * (pow((1+5/100), 1)) - 1500000`.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Can you edit the question to add a short program that reproduces the wrong result?

Comment: Please edit the question to make this a [mcve] - what *exactly* are you doing that has the output you say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you have misarranged arguments in your call to compound_interest.

Shouldl have:

```
c = compound_interest(a,r,y)
```

Rather than:

```
c = compound_interest(a,y,r)
```

Side note:
In founction compound_interest numbers are already float, so should remove:

```
principle=int(principle)
rate=int(rate)
time=int(time)
```

Otherwise, you can't handle interests such as 5.5, or 1.5 years.

Comment: It's always some idiotic mistake.  Thanks!  And I added the int()s just to try to test, but have removed now.

Comment: @thf--Modification of Murphy law for this would be: "A good programmer makes as many mistakes in a day as the average person in 20 years.  A great one can do it before lunch".

Comment: By this measure I am the greatest.  Be glad you can say you know me.

Answer (score 1):

Parentheses aren't correct.

I get `1575000.0` with this:

```
amount = principle * pow(1 + rate/100, time)
```

Comment: Tried this, same result (note I edited the program to use this instead because it's cleaner)